# Refrescar JPanel

Tags: java

En esta parte del código intento actualizar el `jpanel` para que los `jlabel` se muevan poco a poco y aparezca una especia de animación pero mi problema es que me muestra todos los `jlabel` colocados hasta el final en su lugar en lugar de hacer esa pequeña animación, ¿como resuelvo este problema?

```
int nuevoContador = 0;
int labelCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < reinas; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < reinas; k++) {
            String xy = jugadas.get(nuevoContador).get(k);
            String[] coordenadas = xy.split("\\|");
            int[] numCor = new int[2];

            for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
                numCor[l] = Integer.parseInt(coordenadas[l]);
            }

            System.out.println("Nuevo margen: " + coordenadas[0] + " - " + coordenadas[1]);
            if (numCor[0] != 0 || numCor[1] != 0) {
                label[labelCount].setLocation(numCor[0], numCor[1]);
                labelCount++;
            }
        }
        nuevoContador++;
        System.out.println("Contador: " + nuevoContador);
    }
    jpanel.updateUI();
    labelCount = 0;
    System.out.println("Jugada Marcada");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(OtraPrueba.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo lo de que muestra todos los jlabel, quiere decir que no se borra cada label tras "avanzar"?  O que la animación no se ejecuta sino que saltan al final?

Comment: Solo esta poniendo nuevas coordenadas a los labels existentes